# Get steam video from wireless camera without application

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering

I am making a project for my car, some kind of custom multimedia based on OrangePi + Ubuntu. One of the features I want is a rear view camera. Those cameras always have CBVS, and as I've figured out there's no way to make my Pi decode analog video signal. Also, It has only one USB port and it's already in use.

So, my idea was to buy a cheap wireless rear view cam, which requires an iOS/Android device with app installed on it to steam video, unpack .apk and try to figure out how an app pulls signal from camera, and to replicate that to run on my Ubuntu. Just video, nothing else.

So I did, but after unpacking .apk with Apktool I couldn't find anything useful and got completely lost in that code, cuz I don't have any android dev experience.

Could someone help me with that?
What I was trying to reach is kinda rtsp URL or smth, some kind of endpoint which I could reach from Ubuntu without that app.

Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance!
APK could be found here http://www.spd-sz.com/W-Car_2.9.13.apk